# Graphics contents get erased on maximized

Tags: java, swing, jframe, graphics2d

I am developing a GUI painting application.  But the problem is that the frame contents get erased on minimizing and then maximizing.  I know what the problem is, it's that paint is called again after maximizing and the frame's contents are not handled properly.  But I could not solve the behavior even after knowing the error.

Here is the main code responsible for this behavior:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    /*From minimized to maximized*/
    System.err.println("Inside paint now ");
   try{
    if(color==colour.red)
        g.setColor(Color.red);
    else if(color==colour.green)
        g.setColor(Color.green);
    else if(color==colour.pink)
        g.setColor(Color.PINK);
    else if(color==colour.cyan)
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    else if(color==colour.magenta)
        g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    else if(color==colour.orange)
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    else if(color==colour.white)
        g.setColor(Color.white);
    else if(color==colour.black)
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    else if(color==colour.yellow)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        System.out.println("Colour selected ");
    }
    else if(stat==state.line)
    {
            Point p=getMousePosition();

            x=p.x;y=p.y;
            System.out.append("In here ");
            System.out.append("the point is "+x+" "+y);
            if(prevx==0 && prevy==0)
            {
                g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
            //    System.out.append("the point is "+x+" "+y);
            }
            else
            g.drawLine(x, y, prevx, prevy);
            prevx=x;
            prevy=y;
            System.out.println("Line selected ");
    }
    else  if(stat==state.rectangle)
    {
          if(x<prevx)
          {
                x=x+prevx;
                prevx=x-prevx;
                x=x-prevx;
          }
          if(y<prevy)
          {
                y=y+prevy;
                prevy=y-prevy;
                y=y-prevy;
          }
          g.drawRect(prevx,prevy,x-prevx,y-prevy);
          System.out.println("Rectangle selected ");
     }
     else if(stat==state.circle)
     {
            if(x<prevx)
            {
                x=x+prevx;
                prevx=x-prevx;
                x=x-prevx;
            }
            if(y<prevy)
            {
                y=y+prevy;
                prevy=y-prevy;
                y=y-prevy;
            }
            g.drawOval(prevx,prevy,x-prevx,y-prevy);
            System.out.println("Circle selected ");
     }
     else  if(stat==state.ruler)
     {
            g.drawLine(x, y, prevx, prevy);
            System.out.println("Ruler selected ");
     }
     else if(stat==state.eraser)
     {
            g.setColor(getBackground());
            g.fillRect(x-10, y-10, 20, 20);
            System.out.println("Eraser selected ");
     }
     else
     {
           System.out.append("nothing done");
     }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: And you're overriding `paint` instead of `paintComponent` because...?

Comment: What exactly is being painted here?  Or better still, where is the [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: Empty catch `catch(Exception e){}`? So that **if** something goes wrong, at least nobody will notice? I suggest adding `e.printStackTrace();`. And see what it prints.

Comment: BTW - don't ever `catch(Exception e){}` in broken code.  Instead at least `catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}` or better still, use a logging framework. @Ishtar beat me by around a minute.  +1

Answer (score 1):

My vote is mkrhrts's comment, that you're overriding `paint` when you're supposed to override `paintComponent`.

Overriding `paint` is bad practice, and you don't appear to be doing any of the following to ensure it doesn't break:

- call `super.paint()`
- call `paintComponent`, `paintBorder`, or `paintChildren`

Check out the [documentation for the paint method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29).